# How can I search without asking a question in the Android App?

Tags: support, search, android-app

How can one search Stack Overflow via the Android application without asking a question?

Comment: google keeps the data for SO very up to date, so: "nullreference datatable site:stackoverflow.com"

Comment: Dunno about Android, but on a laptop I often start a question and type in the title and a few more details, then see what is listed for possible matches.  I find this works MUCH better than the brain-dead search function.

Comment: @Plutonix Specifying the site is probably redundant anyway as most Google searches I do lead to SO anyway :)

Comment: SO will rank high in a standard search, but "unsited" that example balloons from 5k to 39k results with only 2 SO entries on the first page.  The other results may be good, but the Q was how to search the site.

Comment: To be honest, I find that composing a good question (without actually posting it) usually yields far better 'results' than using the search tool.

Comment: Superstringcheese: I take it one step further. Compose a good question, and if you don't find a relevant answer, post it. :)

Answer (score 36):

[image: SO Android search box]

Comment: Would be nice if it actually worked.  But plain old Google does much better, and neither is very good at handling context.

Comment: @HotLicks While this is true, the OP did _explicitly_ say "via the Android application" in the question. So this answer is 100% correct. Not the best way, but 100% what was asked for.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but it's worth remembering that a great answer to a terrible question isn't always the right answer; at the very least it's worth editing the observation from your comment into your answer.

Comment: Your answers resolved my question.  I was in 'User' and 'Feed' options which have no search bar.  Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

Not exactly the answer you want, but by far the best way to do this is to not use the app, but instead use the Google search functionality your phone almost certainly has.

In fact, even on the desktop, Google in a browser works much better than the Stack Exchange search functionality.

Answer (score 7):

Use Google Search to search StackOverflow, like this:

[`how to remove spaces between inline block elements site:stackoverflow.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20remove%20spaces%20between%20inline%20block%20elements%20site%3Astackoverflow.com)

StackOverflow's built-in search blows.

Comment: "StackOverflow's built-in search blows"... I've seen that comment a lot lately... would it be a good idea to propose a "StackOverflow search (powered by Google)" feature?

Comment: StackExchange.com does that already.

Comment: Yep, but very very badly, for some reason